# Console shutdown mechanism

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net, console

I'm trying to create an effiecent way to shut down my console application. To do this I have a while loop in my program's main method waiting for a request to shutdown.

```
var rebootAfterClose = false;

while (true)
{
    var input = Console.ReadKey();

    if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.C && input.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control)
    {
        break;
    }

    if (input.Key != ConsoleKey.R || input.Modifiers != ConsoleModifiers.Control)
    {
        continue;
    }

    rebootAfterClose = true;

    break;
}

Server?.Stop(rebootAfterClose);
```

I then have these methods, the stop is the one that gets called, Dispose gets called in Stop().

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (Disposing)
    {
        return;
    }

    Disposing = true;

    BaseHandler.PlayerHandler.Dispose();

    ConsoleUpdater.Dispose();
    SocketHandler.Dispose();
}

public void Stop(bool restart)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var shutdownMessage = PlusEnvironment.GetLanguageManager().TryGetValue("server.shutdown.message");
        var shutdownPacket = new BroadcastMessageAlertComposer(shutdownMessage);

        Program.Server.BaseHandler.PlayerHandler.SendPacketToPlayers(shutdownPacket);

        ConsoleUpdater.Stop();

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Title = "Stopping...";

        Logger.Warn("Server is " + (restart ? "rebooting" : "shutting down") + "....");

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        // not sure if I should use this instead? : Task.Delay(5000);

        Dispose();

        if (restart)
        {
            Process.Start(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        }

        Environment.Exit(0);
    });
}
```

I used a thread as I didn't want to block the thread with the 5 second delay. I'm currently looking to just tidy this mechanism up as I am really new to multithreading and just want to know if I did okay, I appreciate everyone who contributes a comment or answer.

Another thing I'm worried about is the while (true) loop in my main method, is there any better way to do this? I need to avoid closing the console application on any other key other than the ones in the while loop (<kbd>CTR</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>], or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) but I can't think of a better way to do that.

Comment: I'd be better if you posted the complete `Program` class rather then just snippets or whatever your class is called.

Comment: There is literally 1 line `Server = new Server();` and that's the rest of it, I would of posted it if it was relevant in any way.